How to Dynamically Update ValidAudiences in JWT Authentication during Runtime in ASP.NET Core?
I am developing an ASP.NET Core application that uses JWT (JSON Web Tokens) for authentication and authorization.
Current Implementation:
I have set up JWT authentication and configured the ValidAudiences parameter to validate audience claims.
Specific Challenges:
I want to dynamically update the ValidAudiences list at runtime through an API endpoint, but I'm unsure how to implement this so that the changes are reflected in the JWT middleware without restarting the application.
Questions:
How can I effectively update the ValidAudiences at runtime so that the JWT middleware recognizes the new values for subsequent requests?
Environment:
I am using ASP.NET Core version 8.
Any guidance or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
Using IOptionsMonitor:
I implemented IOptionsMonitor to potentially update the ValidAudiences dynamically, but I’m not sure how to ensure that the JWT middleware picks up these changes immediately.
Creating an Update Endpoint:
I created a controller endpoint intended to update the ValidAudiences list, but I faced challenges in ensuring that the updated audiences are recognized by the authentication middleware for subsequent requests.
What I Expected:
I expected that after calling the update endpoint, the changes to ValidAudiences would be immediately reflected in the JWT middleware, allowing tokens with the new audiences to be validated correctly without requiring a restart of the application.
public class Startup {
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<JwtSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings"));

    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("your_secret_key")),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "your_issuer",
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudiences = // How can I dynamically set this?
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
            });

    services.AddControllers();
}}


I'm open to any custom approaches or alternative solutions that might help me achieve the desired functionality. If you have any suggestions, please share!

Yes you could use IOptionsMonitor to achieve this like following.
[HttpGet("change")]
public void Change()
{
    var serviceProvider = HttpContext.RequestServices;
    var jwtoptionsMonitor = serviceProvider.GetService<IOptionsMonitor<JwtBearerOptions>>();
    var jwtoptions = jwtoptionsMonitor.Get(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    jwtoptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new[] { "newAudientce"};
}

Any change to this jwtoptions resolved from options monitor will take effect immediately.

Thank you for the information on using IOptionsMonitor for JWT options.  Can i apply this case to gateway?

@CavidHaciyev Do you mean a gateway middlware? could you share some code?

https://www.imghippo.com/i/a4PJv1727085678.png   https://resimlink.com/tRQVvrp1Uy    in this case, I can set ValidAudiences only when the app is first run, but I need new ValidAudiences to be added when I add an Audience from the app setting during runtime.
Note: this is a gateway project
